# Time series plot in R, with yaxis unclear in R

Tags: r, lattice

I wrote the following code to make time series plot by group.

```
nsplot<- xyplot(conc ~ time |Location, data=nspm1long, 
                ylim=range(nspm1long$conc),
                main="PM1 time series by Location", 
                ylab="PM1 concentration (mg/m3)",  
                xlab="Time", type="l",
                par.strip.text=list(cex=0.7), 
                par.settings=list(axis.text=list(cex=0.7)))
print(nsplot)
```

What I got is a block of thick line for the y-axis instead of the tickmarks like the x-axis.  Would someone please help me fix the code.  It would be even better if I could control the range of ylim like 0-0.5 and the number of tick marks.

I don't know how to attach the image here and perhaps you could show me how too.

Comment: Try editing your question to include the output of `str(nspm1long)`. That may shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your code looks fine for me. Here is what I get with some example data I made:

```
set.seed(12345)
data = expand.grid(time=1:100, Location=factor(1:3))
data$conc = with(data, 0.1*time + as.numeric(Location)) + rnorm(nrow(data))
```

[image]

See `?xyplot` for the answers to all your plot formatting questions, specifically the `scales`, `tick.number`, `ylim`, `tck` parameters.

Comment: Not quite. Your x-axis is not a time variable.  Try something like `time = Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(100)*3600)` which spreads it over a few days.

Comment: Ahh I guess it's unclear from the OP what format `time` is in. I'll update a final version when we know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it for awhile, I learned the problem was caused by NA values in the dataset.  After removing NA values, plot looks ok now.

John - Thank you for your tips about ?xy.  There is a lot of cool stuff in there.
Dirk - I am new to R and time series data manipulation.  I don't know how to use it yet but will keep it in mind